# Why doesn't the code run in its own thread?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

I'm trying to run this code (which *is* working):

```
foreach(Friend f in chatLib.Friends)
{
    chatLib.GetPhoto(f);
    contactWindowControl.AddContactToList(f);
}
```

in it's own thread, in order to not block the UI.
I tried following:

```
chatLib.Friends.ForEach(item => 
    new Thread(() => { 
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<Friend>(chatLib.GetPhoto), item); 
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<Friend>(contactWindowControl.AddContactToList), item); 
    })
);
```

I also tried without *Lambda*.

**GetPhoto** (From chat libary)

```
public void GetPhoto(Friend contact)
{
    VcardIq viq = new VcardIq(IqType.get, new Jid(contact.jid));
    IQ iq = xmpp.IqGrabber.SendIq(viq);

    if (iq != null && iq.Type == IqType.result)
    {
        Vcard vcard = iq.Vcard;
        if (vcard != null)
        {
            contact.photo = vcard.Photo.Image;
            contact.hasPhoto = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**AddContactToList** (From code behind of usercontrol)

```
public void AddContactToList(Friend contact)
{
    contactScroll.Children.Add(new ContactWindowContact(contact));
}
```

Comment: What do you think `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` does?

Comment: I thought it will run the code in the right thread to give access to the controls hosted in the usercontrol?

Comment: So you're telling the code to run in the UI thread, then asking us why it isn't running in its own thread? What?

Comment: Okay I understand it :) Thats why I love stackoverflow, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're doing nothing in the threads, basically you're saying create a new thread, and on it register code with the Dispatcher so that code runs on the UI thread.

There's no magical "make things threaded", and what you're doing it creating a thread, and then pushing the work you want to do in it back to the original thread.

What you need to do is make your code so that getphoto returns what you need and does NOT update anything used on your UI thread (so anything bound to xaml / anything in the tree) and then when you're done doing that work call the dispatcher passing it only the code to update the data

Also you really shouldn't create your own threads for this, just use tasks or better yet since you're already using foreach switch to parallel.foreach

```
Parallel.Foreach(chatLib.Friends,item=>
{
    // This runs in parallel, do the expensive work here and NOT Inside Dispatcher
    item.Photo = chatLib.getPhoto(item);

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
    {
        // This will run on the UI thread, only do updates here
        contactWindowControl.AddContactToList(item);
    });
});
```

Comment: That absolutely makes sense! Thanks for explaining!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use tasks instead of the dispatcher.

Your code would look like this:

```cs
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach(Friend f in chatLib.Friends)
{
    Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew( ( arg ) => 
    {chatLib.GetPhoto(arg); contactWindowControl.AddContactToList(arg); }, f );
    tasks.Add(task);
}
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```